# Mac Won't Mount Linux External Drive

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, external-disk, filesystem

When I plug in an external hard drive, I get "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer". The "Disk Utility" applications sees the physical drive, but doesn't show any partitions. If I use `diskutil list`, I get:

```
~ diskutil list

dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                      Linux                         1.0 TB     disk2s1
```

I don't know what exact file system is used on that drive. I know ext4 is the most popular, but this hard drive is from a few years ago, and may be something else.

I tried to install support for ext4

```
brew cask install osxfuse
```

then reboot system, then:

```
brew install ext4fuse
```

and still get the same outcome.

I need to read the data off of the drive. FYI, I'm running OS X Sierra.

Any ideas?

Comment: See this post:  https://superuser.com/questions/197669/macfuse-ext4fuse-no-luck

Comment: That thread is from 2010-2011, and the MacFuse project has been replaced by Fuse for MacOS, which is what I installed.